# Android app which forwards all incoming SMSes to my email address

Tags: android, sms

I am looking for an app that can take all SMS messages received by my phone and forward them to my email address. I need it for Android 4.0+.

Comment: Why do you need this?  Why not just read your SMSes on your phone?  :)

Comment: @unforgettableid: Could be for traceability, or for reading SMS from a phone which is not physically accessible (maybe at work? haha)

Comment: @unforgettableid The reason is because my bank in India sends me a secure password every time I do a transaction and If I do not have my mobile (if I am abroad) it is a pain to do such transactions- I have to call home every time to get it. I requested the bank to send me an email instead of an SMS but they cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My list of [SMS Forwarder](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_contacts_shortmessage#group_82) apps tells me **[SMS Forwarder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yas.freeSmsForwarder)** should be a good candidate:

- **Supports Android 4.0+:** Yes, 2.3 and up.
- **Forwards incoming SMS to e-mail:** Yes, e-mail and other phonme numbers are supported
- **Forwards *all* incoming SMS:** Your choice. It even allows to forward messages from selected senders.

[image: SMS forwarder] [image: SMS forwarder]
<sup>Screenshots (source: [Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.yas.freeSmsForwarder); click images for larger variants)</sup>

I'm not using this app myself (I rarely deal with SMS), but it has a pretty good rating at *Google Play* (4.2 stars at over 2,500 votes), so I feel confident this is a good recommendation. And other than *SMS Gateway* (which [was recommended in this answer](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/23370/185) and had its last update in 6/2012), *SMS Forwarder* seems to be still maintained actively (last update 5/2015, as of this writing). For alternatives, just follow the first link to my list :)

Answer (score 1):

[SMS gateway](https://play.google.com/store/apps/detailshttps://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=eu.apksoft.android.smsgateway) does what you need and more.

It is essentially a gateway between SMS and other forms of electronic communication.

What you are trying to do can be done using the forward to smtp option. You would have to configure it with gmail or some other smtp server in the smtp settings of the app.

Answer (score 0):

- [Post My SMS - SMS to Email](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.gingellica.postmysms&hl=en)
- [SMS Auto Reply and Forward](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.canarys.sms.autoreplysms&hl=en)

These use your Google account instead of requiring account details (smtp/email/password).